# Use 2 DHT22 AND PASS THE DATA TO SD Error File data does not exsist

Tags: sensors, sd-card, temperature-sensor, compilation-errors, error

anyone can help me please to fix this error when I try to compilate says File does not exsist. It would be great if anyone can post the entirely code.

Link of code below if anyone can help me please:

https://create.arduino.cc/editor/Jawad2001/5ea57339-7ca1-4f8d-ab00-f4f1aa639209/preview

error: expected')' before 'f'

Sorry I'm new at this sorry for the annoyances.

Thanks For all your Help.

Comment: `#include <SD.h>;`

Comment: I don't know why but says expected initializer  before "." token

Comment: sorry, without `;`. it should be `#include <SD.h>`

Comment: I know but i did it without ;

Comment: i don't know why but the program says the error is in Filedata2.txt

Comment: this line is defining a variable `File data.txt;`  (it is actually an object) .... you cannot have a period `.` in a variable name, maybe use an underline instead. `File data_txt;`

Comment: It helped but now i have other problem in void get data

Comment: data_file was not declared in this scope i publicated the new errors

Comment: @jawadbouhali, i formatted the error printout so that it was readable and you messed it up again ...... please use the `{}` to format the error printout

Comment: `data_file was not declared in this scope` ..... are you saying that you declared the variable name `data_file`?   ..... where did you declare it? ....... please look at the errors one at a time and try to figure out why they are being presented ....... do not look at all of the errors at the same time, that leads to confusion

Comment: The code needs to be inside the post, not behind a link.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several things I can see from your code that cause most of the error messages.

**1)** You declare

```
File data_txt;
File data2_txt;
```

but you later use `data_file` and `data_file2`. This is why you see the "not declared in this scope" errors.

**2)** You do not properly define the functions `getData()` and `getData2()`. You start with the definition of `getData2()` inside the function `getData()`.
First finish the function `getData()` by closing all brackets you opened and then define the function `getData2()`, like this:

```
void getData() {
//the code of getData() goes here....
}

void getData2() {
//the code of getData2() goes here....
}
```

**3)** I assume you want to write to `data_file` in `getData()` and to `data_file2` in `getData2()`?! Nevertheless, you also use `data_file` in `getData2()`.

**Update after your edit:**

Regarding the compilation error, you do not open a curly bracket

**{**

after `getData2()`.

However, there are several other issues that will lead to problems, even if it finally does compile without problems.